# Modify list template in flask admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I am using flask and the [Flask-Admin](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) extension. I have two models (using sql alchemy):

- Project
- Task

Project has the attribute:

```
tasks = db.relationship('Task', backref=db.backref('project'))
```

And tasks are a self referential tree structure with the key column in Task:

```
children = db.relationship("Task",

       # cascade deletions
       cascade="all, delete-orphan",

       # many to one + adjacency list - remote_side
       # is required to reference the 'remote'
       # column in the join condition.
       backref=db.backref("parent", remote_side=id),

       # children will be represented as a dictionary
       # on the "title" attribute.
       collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('title'),
       )
```

I want to have a list template from Flask-Admin that shows me all Projects. This is easily done with the extension and the standard list view. But now I want to add the CRUD Interface (Example: http://examples.flask-admin.org/sqla/simple/admin/userview/) for the tasks that should appear upon clicking each on a project.

I don't know what is the best way to reach this goal. I thought about including an iframe for the Task in each table cell of a project row. But this is somehow ugly. How can I render the CRUD interface for the tasks belonging to its project in the project list template?

I know that Flask-Admin is able to link the two tables together (over the foreign keys in the model), but the standard way is not what I want, since it needs at least one click from getting from the project crud interface to the task crud interface. What I want is to have the both crud interfaces loaded on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation it looks like this is as simple as providing an [`inline-models`](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_contrib_sqla/#flask.ext.admin.contrib.sqla.ModelView.inline_models) class property to your `Project` model view:

```
class ProjectModelView(ModelView):
    inline_models = (Task, )
```

Comment: Will have a look on it! Huge thanks for your answer, I really spent some time on this problem.